# Sqlite.NET doesn't know about int[]?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

When I try to save a model in sqlite.net which has an `int[]` property I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Int32[]
```

Is this expected? How can I save this - surely it should be ok doing this?

Comment: What is the field type in your database, out of interest?

Comment: Do you know a database having an array as type ?

Comment: good point @RaphaëlAlthaus - I wasn't thinking about this right!

Comment: [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-data-types)? Granted I'm 2 years late to the argument though :P

Comment: lol cheers dude - on SO I believe the phrase "better late than never" has never been more apt. Hopefully it will help someone who stumbles across this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the SQLite [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs), SQLite.NET only supports the following types:

- Boolean
- Byte
- UInt16
- UInt32
- Int64
- Single
- Double
- Decimal
- String
- SByte
- Int16
- Int32
- DateTime
- byte[]
- Guid
- Enum

Integer arrays are not supported (nor would I expect it to.. can't really turn it into a blob)

Comment: Well, you could save as a blob if you decided what the serialization format was…

Comment: @DonalFellows: I suppose you could, but it's "SQLite" so I expect a basic implementation.. May even be too unnatural for them to implement. I have serialized objects to databases in Java but not in C# and in Java it is just a giant string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use byte[] type to store int32[] type. Just split every int into 4 byte values ;)